# Set of invertible linear operators is open

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

**Statement:** Let $X$ be a banach spase. We denote by $B(X,X)$ the set of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $X$. Then the set of all invertible maps in $B(X,X)$ is open in $B(X,X)$.

**Proof:** Take invertible $T \in B(X,X)$. When $||S|| < ||T^{-1}||^{-1}, ||T^{-1}S||\leq ||T^{-1}|| \cdot||S|| < 1$.

By a proven Lemma we can say that $I+T^{-1}S$ is invertible. Then $T \cdot (I+T^{-1}S)$ is also invertible.

**Question:**
I do not see how this proves the statement. I would have started in the following way:

Let $\Omega$ be the set of invertible functions s.t. $\Omega \subset B(X,X)$. My goal is to show that for any $T \in \Omega$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $||S-T|| < \delta \implies S \in B(X,X)$.

From the question here: [Open subsets of the space of linear operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542301/open-subsets-of-the-space-of-linear-operators) I see that $||S-T|| < ||T^{-1}||^{-1}$ implies that $S$ is invertible. Using that I can conclude that $\Omega$ is open.

I don't get it how they proved this in the first proof. Following is not clear:

- I learned that if $||T^{-1}S|| < 1 \implies I -T^{-1}S$ invertible. Is the same true for $I +T^{-1}S$?
- The multiplication of two invertible operators is invertible. I get that. But how does the fact that $T \cdot (I+T^{-1}S)$ is invertible allow me to conclude the statement?

Comment: $T(I+T^{-1}S)=T+S.$ Hence $T+S$ is invertible for any $\|S\|<\delta:=\|T^{-1}\|^{-1}.$ This means that the open ball $B_\delta(T)$ is contained in the set of invertible operators.

Comment: So $T+S$ is invertible and since $T$ is invertible, also $S$ is invertible?

Comment: No. If $T$ is invertible then $T+S$ is invertible if $S$ is small enough, e.g. $\|S\|<\delta.$ The operator $S$ can be $0.$ Every operator $U$ close to $T$ can be represented as $U=T+S,$ where $S$ is close to $0.$

Comment: Ah, I got it! Is $I+T^{-1}S$ always invertible when $||T^{-1}S|| < 1$? Is the proof similar to the other case?

Comment: $\|T^{-1}S\|=\|-T^{-1}S\|$